# Can you use a Neo4j database created on a Windows machine as data volume of Neo4j on Docker?

Tags: docker, neo4j

I have installed Neo4j (3.0.4) on my Windows Machine (Win 10 Pro). Recently I started to experiment with Docker. First I used the Docker Toolbox, last week I switched to Docker for Windows. I pulled the Neo4j image and read that it was possible to map a Docker data volume to an already existing Neo4j instance on my host machine. However when I tried to create this mapping I ran into problems.

My Neo4j instances on my host are located in a C:/Users/… subfolder. As I understood, this folder should by default be shared between the host and guest system. To be sure however, I explicitly shared my whole C-drive as explained in [this post](https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c#.gpj61r46p).

In order to map my folder with a specific Neo4j database (hereafter called: MyGraphDB), I started the Neo4j container with the following command: `docker run --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 -v c:/users/<My Subpath>/Neo4j/MyGraphDB.graphdb:/data neo4j`

When I opened the Neo4j UI in my browser I got a new empty database. I tried to verify which databases I could find in my Docker container by means of the following commands:

```
Docker exec -it <ContainerName> /bin/bash

ls /data
```

It contained only 2 folders:

- databases
- dbms

So apparently the mapping was not created.

Next I tried to map my folder containing al my Neo4j databases with the docker container by slightly adjusting the docker command: `docker run –publish=7474:7474 –publish=7687:7687 -v c:/users/<My Subpath>/Neo4j:/data neo4j`

When I verified the content of the data folder in my container I now found 3 folders:

- MyFirstGraphDB
- databases
- dbms

So apparently it had mapped the first database from my host machine’s folder, but that folder contained 5 databases. And when I looked in the “MyFirstGraphDB” folder in my container it was almost empty. Although on my host machine it is quite big and contains many files and subfolders.

Due to these problems (and because it took already quite some time) I was now wondering if it is actually possible to share Neo4j databases that were created on Windows with Neo4j on Docker? Neo4j data seems to be organized differently on Windows and Linux. Before continueing my experiments I would therefore prefer to be sure that it is actually feasible.